# Spoof Referer header in request header and DOM

Tags: http, exploit, referer

I'm looking for an IE addon or any similar solution, which can spoof the Referer in both the HTTP request header, and the document DOM. 
I am using Fiddler to set the Referer in the HTTP request header, but the document.referrer variable is still empty, and I want to set it to a fixed string. 
I need this for automated exploit kit crawling, because some infected sites check both the request header and the document.referer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, solved it :)

In Fiddler:

```
static function OnBeforeResponse(oSession: Session) {

if (oSession.oResponse.headers.ExistsAndContains("Content-Type","text/html")) {
    oSession.utilDecodeResponse();

    var oBody = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(oSession.responseBodyBytes);
    var oRegEx = /(<\/head>)/i;
    oBody = oBody.replace(oRegEx, "<script type='text/javascript'>if ((window.document.referrer == '') || (typeof window.document.referrer === 'undefined' )) {window.document.__defineGetter__('referrer', function () {return 'http://google.com/';})};</script>$1");

    oSession.utilSetResponseBody(oBody);
}

}
```